# Not working Custom HTTP Error Pages in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, error-handling, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5.2

I wanted to change this error :

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

first please see : [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#custom-http-error-pages)

I created a new file `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` but my app error didn't change !

it change just when not found `url` at `route` but when insert url injection in to $_GET it show "whoops .." yet

for example work for this link : `http://domain.com/dgdgergehrhddg54d6g8`

but not working for this injection : `http://domain.com/listmanage=8` insert `9` instens of 8

error message when debug is true :

> ErrorException: file.php line 215
>
> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: where did you change debug mode from env file or config? and did you try to access undefined route or send abort(404) to test?

Comment: FYI: "Whoops, [...]" errors in Laravel are HTTP 5XX errors, not 404.

Comment: i remove line  `APP_DEBUG` in env file and changed debug mode from config- no- how can send abort(404) or try to access undefined route?

Comment: 5XX ? what is you mean? i trye to add `500.blade.php` but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You are viewing that error page because of the environment you are into.
As default, for local environments, the "Whoops" format is shown.
For Production environments, the error/x.blade.php files are used.

To customize this you simply go to: ./app/Exceptions/Handler.php
And modify the `render` function. You can do something like this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    // If an ErrorException is received and this enviroment is local
    if ($e instanceof \ErrorException && app()->environment() == 'local') {
        // Show customized page
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], $e->getCode());
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);

}
```

Cheers :)

Comment: my app is not installed in localhost it is on VPS , so i should change `APP_ENV=local` in ENV file? and what is `\ErrorException` inside `if` commend im new user please description exactly thanks

Comment: no, your APP_ENV=production is fine then. Can you post the content of the Handler.php file? And, an ErrorException is the event that Laravel fires when an error is occurring.

Comment: yes i posted the content of the `Handler.php` but it did not work !

Comment: @MikelWilliams don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

on Larvel 5.2 on your `app/exceptions/handler.php` just extend this method `renderHttpException` ie add this method to `handler.php`

```
/**
 * Render the given HttpException.
 *
 * @param  \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException  $e
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function renderHttpException(HttpException $e)
{

   // to get status code ie 404, 503, 500
    $status = $e->getStatusCode();

    if (view()->exists("errors.{$status}")) {
        return response()->view("errors.{$status}", ['exception' => $e], $status, $e->getHeaders());
    } else {
        return $this->convertExceptionToResponse($e);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.